# Changing color profile and refresh rate for a specific monitor via script in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, colors, color-profiles, refresh-rate

I'd like to know whether it is possible to both change the color profile (either to a specific .icm file or to a previously imported one) and the refresh rate (e.g. 60Hz -> 120Hz, also just switching between pre-defined profiles) using a script in Windows 7?

I'm the owner of a monitor with a bypass board so I'm able to overclock my 2560x1440 panel to 120Hz, which puts quite a strain on the Dual-link DVI cable (483MHz pixel clock) and thus slightly falsifies the colors. I am able to partly counter that using another color profile which suffices for purposes like gaming, but when returning to normal activities I've got to switch back, and switching both the refresh rate and the color profile takes around 3 minutes each time.

I tried searching the Windows API docs (which I am not familiar with) for anything related and found [this entry on monitor configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692965(v=vs.85).aspx), but it doesn't seem to be as extensive as I need it.